# maven-flyway-plugin does not exist or no valid version could be found. Error on mvn cmd line in Windows, but runs OK inside Eclipse

Tags: maven, flyway

I can run a flyway migration from inside Eclipse, but not from the DOS command line in Windows.  I am running maven 2.2.1, Eclipse Indigo Service Release 1
Build id: 20110916-0149.

Other developers on the same project do not get this error. 
I have searched StackOverflow, http://flywaydb.org/, etc but do not see anyone else with this speccific problem.

The error I get is:- 
The plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-flyway-plugin' does not exist or no valid version could be found

Comment: Without a pom file and the full output error messages etc. it's hard to guess what's wrong. I assume you have given a wrong version etc. but not sure.

Comment: Thanks khmarbaise, I have been continuing to look at the problem and I have a fix.  I will add an answer shortly. Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this by upgrading from maven 2.2.1 to maven 3.0.4.
Ref:- http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/maven/maven-3/3.0.4/binaries/apache-maven-3.0.4-bin.zip

Runs as expected now.